How to unit test import error of a module that is actually available at testime?
How can I mock an import error of the module foo in the unit test?
# file: bla.py
try: 
    import foo

except ImportError: 
    print("error")
    sys.exit(1)

Baseline for the unit test:
import bla
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # what to mock (or so) here in order to raise the 'ImportError' that then raises the `sys.exit(1)`
    def test_1(self):
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as err:
            importlib.reload(bla) # force reload, but fails as 'foo' is not importable
        self.assertEqual(rt.exception.code,1)


What is rt in the instruction rt.exception.code?

You can import the bla module inside the test (and remove the import bla at the top of the test file). Furthermore you have to remove the instruction importlib.reload() from the test method.
Below there is your test file with my changes:
#import bla    <--- REMOVE THIS IMPORT
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # what to mock (or so) here in order to raise the 'ImportError' that then raises the `sys.exit(1)`
    def test_1(self):
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as err:
            import bla # <------ THE IMPORT OF bla IS HERE
            # remove the following instruction because it is not executed
            #importlib.reload(bla) # force reload, but fails as 'foo' is not importable
        # I suppose that in the assertEqual you would like use 'err' and not 'rt'
        #self.assertEqual(rt.exception.code,1)
        self.assertEqual(err.exception.code, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

In this way the test is passed, so this proofs that:

it is raised the Exception SystemExit (by the instruction sys.exit(1) present in the bla module)
the code of the Exception raised is 1 because you pass the integer 1 to the instruction sys.exit(1) in except block defined in the bla module

